# How to set List with unchecked checkboxes in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am using custom list adapter to show list with checkbox, text and Date like this.

[checkbox] - [TextView] - [Date]

I am populating list from database but now I want is, if I check one list item then it got completed and fade out from the listview also status in database should be true using update set query but I don't want to delete it from database. How to set list with items those are not checked.

my custom adapter:

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

    private List<Task> dataitem;
    private Activity activity;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, List<Task> items) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.dataitem = items;
    this.activity = a;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tasklistTitle;
    public TextView createdDate;
    public CheckBox completedflag;
}

   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.tasklist_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tasklistTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tasklistTitle);
        holder.createdDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.createdDate);
        holder.completedflag = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.completedflag);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    final Task custom = dataitem.get(position);
    if (custom != null) {
        holder.tasklistTitle.setText(custom.getTaskListTitle());
        holder.createdDate.setText(custom.getTaskListCreated());
        holder.completedflag.setText(custom.getTaskListCompletedFlag());
    }
    return v;
}
   public synchronized void refresAdapter(List<Task> dataitems) {
    dataitem.clear();
    dataitem.addAll(dataitems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Is there any need to use OncheckedChecngeListner in this class? I have been through with couple of examples but no use. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I really do not understand your question.
Is this your question: 
1. One checkbox is checked at current time
2. When one checkbox is checked, you want update the checked status to database ( certainly include change the status of previous checked )

Comment: Yes, Exactly, but I don't know how to get unchecked list. Please suggest?

Comment: @hieuxit any further comment?

Comment: okay!
0. Declare a int mStoreCheckedPosition = -1; // Save a current checked position
1. You setTag for Checkbox on every item is its position (on getView() function, holder.completedflag.setTag(position)) 
2. You use OncheckedChecngeListner to determine what is checkbox is checked (checked == true) and check the condition
 if(mStoreCheckedPosition != -1){
    // updateView 
    int oldCheckedPosition = mStoreCheckedPosition - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View child = listView.getChildAt(oldCheckedPosition);
    // Get holder and setChecked for checked is false
 }
(continue...)

Comment: sorry for comment is very little characters I canot post full, I will post full in answer.

Comment: ok i will wait, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a int mStoreCheckedPosition = -1; // Save a current checked position
2. You setTag for Checkbox on every item is its position (on getView() function, holder.completedflag.setTag(position))
3. You use OncheckedChecngeListner to determine what is checkbox is checked:
   if(checked == true). 
   And follow the guide:

   ```
   if(mStoreCheckedPosition != -1){ 
        // updateView 
        int oldCheckedPosition = mStoreCheckedPosition - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 
        View child = listView.getChildAt(oldCheckedPosition); // Get holder and setChecked for checked is false
        if(child!=null){
            ((ViewHolder)child.getTag()).completedflag.setChecked(false);
        }

   }
   // update database
   int currentCheckedPosition = (Integer)view.getTag();
   // Update database with the currentCheckedPosition is true value and mStoreCheckedPosition is false value
   // finally update mStoreCheckedPosition
   mStoreCheckedPosition = currentCheckedPosition;
   ```

And I suggest you in list adapter you return databaseId for getItemId, and then you use this for update your database